# How to add ripple effect to a Container with decoration in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I want to add a ripple effect to a custom `Container`. I have used `Inkwell` and `Material` widgets to achieve this behavior, but it does not work. The code is as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){},
          child: Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "A box container",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The result is:

[image]

I also used a transparent color on `Container` and the purple color on `Material` as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "A box container",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

As a result, the ripple effect occurs, but the `Container` looks like this (not what I want):

[image]

I also swapped the `Container` and `Material` widgets with each other, applied clip on the `Container` as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "A box container",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Again, the ripple effect occurs, but the `Container` does not look as I want to (you can spot the little difference between the following photo and the first photo, in the edges of the `Container`):

[image]

I want the `Container` to look exactly as in the first photo with a ripple effect.

Note: The behavior that I want, can be exactly achieved through using `Ink` and `Inkwell` widgets, but when used in a `ListView`, it causes item render problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were very close. You needed to have `borderRadius` on  `Material` and `InkWell`. Try it this way

```dart
child: Material(
  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
  child: InkWell(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        "A box container",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]